# How to reinitialize a chart?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, livecharts

I've a class called `CountriesVM` that implements all the properties of the `ViewModel` of a `Country`. Essentially in this class there are some property for the `Charts` available on the window. A simple chart looks like this:

```
<lvc:CartesianChart Series="{Binding AvgWeather}" LegendLocation="Bottom" />
```

the property is declared in the `CountriesVM`:

```
public SeriesCollection AvgWeather{ get; set; } = new SeriesCollection();
```

this working good but I've a problem. I've different charts in my application, each of this have a property binded in the xaml. At some point, the user can clear all the value of the application, so I've created a method that instantiate again all the `ViewModels` classes.

The method have this structure:

```
public void Reset()
{
    CountriesVM = new CountriesVM(); //Initialize again the class
}
```

all the properties are initialized again to the initial value correctly, only the `SeriesCollection` properties 'cause this bug:

> System.NullReferenceException: Reference to an object not set on an object instance.
>      in LiveCharts.Wpf.Series.Erase(Boolean removeFromView) in c:\Users\btord\Documents\Projects\LiveCharts\WpfView\Series.cs:riga 468

I pasted the full stack trace [here](https://pastebin.com/gYB6NB4P).

I can fix this issue clearing each `SeriesCollection` property, but this is insane, I've a lot of properties and it's not an efficient way.

Is this a bug of the library or I missing something?

Comment: Do not clear the entire ViewModel, you should only reset the ItemsSource list. ex: this.AvgWeather = new SeriesCollection(). This collection must implement INotifyPropetyChanged :)

Comment: @pix I know, your solution avoid the problem, but if I need ro instiate again the vm? 'cause in my case doing this is the correct way to go

Comment: well, recrete the entire UserControl dispose the old one and replace it with the new one?

Comment: I already do this, but I got an exception from LiveCharts, all properties are resetted correctly

Comment: @mm8 the file `Series.cs` is related to the library `LiveCharts`